# CSS Problem with Html.TextAreaFor

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-2

I have the following piece of code to give the User a text input box.

```
   <div id="messageEntry" class="grid_3 omega">
      <%= Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.Message) %>
   </div>
```

The input box is only displaying as a small area which I would like to increase. Creating CSS for `id="messageEntry"` has no effect on the size of the box, so how do I increase the size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the HTML cols and rows attributes using the following method signature:

```
HtmlHelper<TModel>, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>>, IDictionary<String, Object>
```

This will allow you to do:

```
<%= Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.Message, new {rows = "50", cols = "50"});
```

Answer (score 2):

apply a css style~

```
<%= Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.Message, 
    new { cols = "40%", @class = "foo" })%>
```

which could look like this:

```
.foo {
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to alter the appearance of the textarea via css, you could use something like this -

```
#messageEntry textarea {width:500px}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but this didn't work. I'm not sure it was able to tie up TextAreaFor with textarea in the CSS.